# Migrate huge cassandra table to another cluster using spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to migrate our old Cassandra cluster to a new one.

**Requirements:-**

I have a cassandra cluster of 10 nodes and the table i want to migrate is ~100GB. I am using spark for migrating the data. My spark cluster has 10 nodes and each node has around 16GB memory.
In the table we have some junk data which i don't want to migrate to the new table. eg:- Let's say i don't want to transfer the rows which has the cid = 1234. So, what is the best way to migrate this using spark job ? I can't put a where filtering on the cassandraRdd directly as the cid is not the only column included in partitioned key.

**Cassandra Table:-**

```
test_table (
    cid text,
    uid text,
    key text,
    value map<text, timestamp>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((cid, uid), key)
)
```

**Sample Data:-**

```
cid   | uid                | key       | value
------+--------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1234 | 899800070709709707 | testkey1  | {'8888': '2017-10-22 03:26:09+0000'}
 6543 | 097079707970709770 | testkey2  | {'9999': '2017-10-20 11:08:45+0000', '1111': '2017-10-20 15:31:46+0000'}
```

I am thinking of something like below. But i guess this is not the best efficient approach.

```
val filteredRdd = rdd.filter { row => row.getString("cid") != "1234" }
filteredRdd.saveToCassandra(KEYSPACE_NAME,NEW_TABLE_NAME)
```

What will be the best possible approach here ?

Comment: Why u thinking, the approach you mentioned is not efficient? You are performing filter on rdd. The filter operation will be a distributed operation by spark. You can go with spark dataframe or dataset filtering approach. But either you perform filter on RDD or DF/DS, it will be distributed and efficient

Answer (score 1):

That method is pretty good. You may want to write it in DataFrames to take advantage of the row encoding but this may only have a slight benefit. The key bottleneck in this operation will be writing and reading from Cassandra.

DF Example

```
spark
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("keyspace", ks)
  .option("table", table)
  .load
  .filter( 'cid !== "1234" )
  .write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("keyspace", ks2)
  .option("table", table2)
  .save
```

Comment: Do you have any sample for this code implementation. looks very easy to implement.

Comment: The above example is a sample code implementation? What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I want to run spark master and worker, Merging two clusters but not keyspaces.I have two clustrer two keyspaces, want to turn to one cluster two keyspaces.